# 2 loops at the same time in c# console application

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, console-application

I'm making a project where it will have the app running for hours checking values every 2 minutes. The problem is that I have two whiles to check two different values.

```
while (Variaveis_importadas[varfossaalarme] != Convert.ToInt32(situacao[3]))
{                
    Thread.Sleep(60000);                
    while (!ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro na função ClientGetVARs. Não foi possivel receber os dados.");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }

    if (ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados foram recebidos.");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.Clear();                
}

while (Variaveis_importadas[varst04] >= Convert.ToInt32(situacao[7]))
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    while (!ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro na função ClientGetVARs. Não foi possivel receber os dados.");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }
    if (ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados foram recebidos.");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.Clear();
}
```

I'd like to know this way they gonna execute at the same time or do they need some other functions so they can execute at the same.

I already saw a class named BackgroundWorker but it only talked about Windows Form Application and not Console Application.

Comment: No, your first loop is going to execute, then your second loop. You could look into timers or threads to run the two concurrently, or you could just have *one* loop which checks both parts every minute. (You say about checking every two minutes, but your main Thread.Sleep is for one minute.)

Comment: You could use Threading for this I'd say.

Comment: BackgroundWorker are used to run code in parallel. It is common in graphical interface so the interface looks responsive (progress bar in one thread, real work in another thread), though it is absolutely not a requirement (i.e. it works in the console)

Comment: look at **await Task.Delay()** instead of **Thread.Sleep();** to avoid blocking the thread

Comment: @JGH that not going to help much with console application... or with running two `while` loops sequentially. `await` will only complicate code even more for beginner...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use timers or check both values at the same time.

```
      while (Variaveis_importadas[varfossaalarme] != 
  Convert.ToInt32(situacao[3]) ||  Variaveis_importadas[varst04] >= 
  Convert.ToInt32(situacao[7]))
   {                
Thread.Sleep(60000);                
while (!ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erro na função ClientGetVARs. Não foi possivel receber os dados.");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.Clear();
}

if (ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Os dados foram recebidos.");
}
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Console.Clear();                
   }
```

Comment: The "||" is the same that "OR" isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Same OR. So you get output if any of those conditions is meet.

Comment: as I can see you are checking those 2 conditions and if true you getting the same output for any of them. So why just not put them together to one condition. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please rate my answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are trying to run your code is only working on a single thread, for doing something simultaniously you need to start a new thread.

You can use Task class from .Net 4.0 i will show you a sample but you need to modify it for your needs

```
Task.Run(() => {

while (Variaveis_importadas[varfossaalarme] != Convert.ToInt32(situacao[3]))
{                
    Thread.Sleep(60000);                
    while (!ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Erro na função ClientGetVARs. Não foi possivel receber os dados.");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }

    if (ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Os dados foram recebidos.");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.Clear();                
}
});

  while (Variaveis_importadas[varst04] >= Convert.ToInt32(situacao[7]))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        while (!ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Erro na função ClientGetVARs. Não foi possivel receber os dados.");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
        }
        if (ClientGetVARs(Variaveis_importadas, varLenght, fHandle_global))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Os dados foram recebidos.");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.Clear();
    }
```

The code above will start an async operation for your first loop and your second loop will run on your main thread. However you will still need to know when to stop your "other" thread, what to do when stopping execution etc..

Btw : Thread.Sleep  will lock their own threads so they wont effect each other.